# constraint solving graduation using HTML Parsing, pandas, and z3

Tags: python, python-3.x, html, parsing, pandas

not sure if this project fits on code review, but my code is getting extremely messy, and would love some tips to clean it up!

## Overview

The project is designed to take in an HTML file (a degree audit), and a couple of course catalog datasets from my University. Then, I output a potential schedule.

Here is an example:

[Input HTML report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JgfCcfSod7XwBKiVjLYplCenpZsFvuKL/view?usp=share_link)
[Input JSON report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--8E8vpzk16HYfVdeKNQ2-t3-1DWuKvU/view?usp=share_link)

Output:

```
{
  "5": [
    "CS 448 - 3 Cr / GPA: 0 (H)",
    "GWS 201 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.5 (E)",
    "EALC 305 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.33 (H)",
    "IS 204 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.64 (E)",
    "MACS 140 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.76 (E)",
    "FSHN 442 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.7 (E)"
  ],
  "6": [
    "AAS 100 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.53 (E)",
    "CI 405 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.72 (E)",
    "CSE 450 - 3 Cr / GPA: 0 (H)",
    "ANTH 350 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.5 (E)",
    "ACE 100 - 4 Cr / GPA: 2.83 (H)"
  ],
  "7": [
    "CS 421 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.39 (H)",
    "ANSC 305 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.69 (E)",
    "LLS 357 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.68 (E)",
    "CS 444 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.56 (E)",
    "KIN 387 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.88 (E)",
    "NPRE 402 - 3 Cr / GPA: 3.51 (E)"
  ]
}
```

Where each number represents the semester to take the course in.

## How it works

I first parse the HTML into a JSON file / object. I then take the object, and my CSV datasets, and perform the following actions:

1. Cleanup input datasets
2. Initialize my two constraints sets: `is_taking_class_constraints` and `semester_constraints`
3. Add minimum / maximum hours per semester, and min/max hard classes per semester
4. Add taken courses
5. Add prerequisite constraints
6. A *large* block to parse all constraints from the JSON object

This generally adds the following types of constraints:

- Take n courses from a list
- Take n hours from alist
- Fulfill at least n out of these k subrequirements

The course list is transformed from a format like `department=None, number="4**"` into a list of courses that meet the criteria. There is also special handling for other cases.

## Parsing

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
import re

SPECIAL_TOPICS = {
    'CS': ['498']
}

def get_req_needs(needs_row):
    # hours number + hourslabel, subreqs number + subreqslabel, count number, countlabel
    hours_needed = needs_row.find('span', class_='hours').text
    subreqs_needed = needs_row.find('td', class_='subreqs').text
    courses = needs_row.find('span', class_='count').text

    return {
        'hours': float(hours_needed or 0),
        'subreqs': int(subreqs_needed or 0),
        'courses': int(courses or 0)
    }

def get_subreq_needs(needs_row):
    hours_text = needs_row.find('td', class_='hours')
    hours_needed = hours_text.text if hours_text is not None else 0
    courses_text = needs_row.find('td', class_='count')
    courses = courses_text.text if courses_text is not None else 0
    # print(needs_row)
    courseslabel_text = needs_row.find('td', class_='countlabel')
    courseslabel = courseslabel_text.text.strip() if courseslabel_text is not None else ''
    if courseslabel == 'COURSES TAKEN' or courseslabel == 'COURSE TAKEN':
        courses = 0

    return {
        'hours': float(hours_needed),
        'courses': int(courses)
    }

def parse_course_select(from_list):
    courses = []
    elements = [child for td in from_list.find_all('td') for child in td.children]
    for i, element in enumerate(elements):
        if type(element) is Tag:
            prev_join_text = elements[i-1].strip() if i > 0 else ','
            next_join_text = elements[i+1].strip() if i < len(elements) - 1 else ','
            next_element = elements[i+2] if i < len(elements) - 2 else None
            department = element['department'].strip()
            course_number = element['number'].strip().split(' ')[0]
            for special_topic in SPECIAL_TOPICS.get(department, []):
                if course_number.startswith(special_topic):
                    # Add section in for special topics
                    course_number = element.find('span', class_='number').text.replace('(X)', '').replace(department, '').strip()
                    break
            next_course_number = None if next_element is None else next_element['number'].strip()

            # Handle wildcard Courses, e.g. take any course in this department
            if course_number == '****':
                courses.append([{
                    'number': None,
                    'department': department
                }])
                continue
            # Handle level courses, e.g. take any 300 level course in this department
            elif course_number.endswith('**'):
                department = None if department == '*****' else department
                courses.append([{
                    'number': course_number,
                    'department': department
                }])
                continue


            if i == len(elements) - 1 or next_join_text in [',', '', '&']:
                if prev_join_text != 'OR':
                    courses.append([{
                        'number': course_number,
                        'department': department
                    }])
            elif next_join_text == 'OR':
                courses.append([{
                    'number': course_number,
                    'department': department,
                },{
                    'number': next_course_number,
                    'department': next_element['department'].strip(),
                }])
            elif next_join_text == 'TO':
                for course_number in range(int(course_number), int(next_course_number)):
                    courses.append([{
                        'number': str(course_number),
                        'department': department
                    }])
            else:
                raise ValueError('Invalid course join text: {}'.format(next_join_text))
    return courses

def parse_audit(html):
    audit = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    reqs_parsed = []
    reqs = audit.find_all('div', class_='requirement')
    courses_taken_section = None
    for req in reqs:
        req_name = req.find('div', class_='reqTitle').get_text("\n").strip()
        req_OK = 'Status_OK' in req["class"] or 'Status_NONE' in req["class"]
        if 'summary of courses taken' in req_name.lower():
            courses_taken_section = req
            continue
        if not req_OK and 'Status_NO' not in req["class"]:
            continue
        

        req_needs = None
        subreqs_parsed = []
        if not req_OK:
            req_table = req.find('tr', class_='reqNeeds')

            # Parse subreqs
            subreqs = req.find_all('div', class_='subrequirement')
            prev_subreq_number = 0
            for subreq in subreqs:
                # print(subreq)
                title = subreq.find('span', class_='subreqTitle')
                status_icon = subreq.find('span', class_='status')['class']
                status_icon_none =  'Status_NONE' in status_icon
                status_icon_ok = 'Status_OK' in status_icon
                subreq_number = subreq.find('span', class_='subreqNumber').text.replace(')', '').strip()
                if subreq_number == 'OR':
                    subreq_number = prev_subreq_number
                elif subreq_number == '':
                    subreq_number = len(subreqs_parsed) + 1
                else:
                    subreq_number = int(subreq_number)
                if title is None:
                    print(f'Warning: NO TITLE, using parent title ({req_name})')
                    subreq_name = f'{req_name}'
                else:
                    subreq_name = title.get_text("\n").strip()
                    if len(subreq_name) == 0:
                        print(f'Warning: EMPTY TITLE, using parent title ({req_name})')
                        subreq_name = f'{req_name}'
                subreq_OK = False
                if status_icon_ok:
                    subreq_OK = True
                elif title is None and req_OK:
                    subreq_OK = True
                elif title is not None and ('srTitle_substatusOK' in title["class"] or 'srTitle_substatusIP' in title["class"]):
                    subreq_OK = True
                # print(subreq_name, subreq_OK, title)
                # print(status_none)
                if title is not None and not subreq_OK and 'srTitle_substatusNO' not in title["class"]:
                    print("Skipping subreq: {}".format(subreq_name))
                    continue

                if courses_taken_section is None and 'courses counting toward' in subreq_name.lower():
                    courses_taken_section = subreq

                from_list = None
                from_list = subreq.find('table', 'selectcourses')
                if from_list:
                    from_list = from_list.find('td', class_='fromcourselist')
                courses = []
                if not subreq_OK and from_list:
                    courses = parse_course_select(from_list)

                # Parse general education subreqs by marking course_list as a string of the req code
                # See https://github.com/wadefagen/datasets/tree/master/geneds#data-format
                gened_lookup_table = {
                    'advanced composition': 'ACP',
                    'cultural studies': 'CS',
                    'humanities & the arts': 'HUM',
                    'natural sciences & technology': 'NAT',
                    'quantitative reasoning': 'QR',
                    'social & behavioral science': 'SBS',
                    'liberal education': 'LIB',
                }
                for key in gened_lookup_table:
                    if key in subreq_name.lower() or key.replace('&', 'and') in subreq_name.lower():
                        assert len(courses) == 0
                        courses = [[{
                            'department': 'GENED',
                            'number': gened_lookup_table[key]
                        }]]
                        break
                
                # This manually fixes up some major requirements where no course list is specified
                # This is for subreqs
                major_subrequirement_lookup_table = {
                    'all technical electives': [{
                        'department': 'CS',
                        'number': '4**'
                    }],
                    'total earned hours': [{
                        'department': None,
                        'number': None
                    }],
                    # https://las.illinois.edu/academics/requirements/minimum
                    'advanced hours completed on this campus': [[{
                        'department': None,
                        'number': '4**',
                    }], [{
                        'department': None,
                        'number': '5**'}]]
                }
                for key in major_subrequirement_lookup_table:
                    if key in subreq_name.lower() :
                        assert len(courses) == 0
                        if len(major_subrequirement_lookup_table[key]) == 1:
                            courses = [major_subrequirement_lookup_table[key]]
                        else:
                            courses = major_subrequirement_lookup_table[key]
                        break
                subreq_needs = None
                table = subreq.find('table', class_='subreqNeeds')
                if table is None:
                    subreq_needs = {
                        'hours': 0,
                        'courses': len(courses)
                    }
                else:
                    subreq_needs = get_subreq_needs(table)
                subreq_needs['course_list'] = courses

                is_none = subreq_needs['hours'] == 0 and subreq_needs['courses'] == 0 and status_icon_none
                subreqs_parsed.append({
                    'name': subreq_name,
                    'subreq_number': subreq_number,
                    'OK': subreq_OK or is_none,
                    'needs': subreq_needs
                })
                prev_subreq_number = subreq_number
            
            if req_table is None:
                req_needs = {
                    'hours': 0,
                    'subreqs': len(list(filter(lambda x: x['OK'] == False, subreqs_parsed))),
                    'courses': 0
                }
            else:
                req_needs = get_req_needs(req_table)

        # Manually fixup some requirements by adding a fake prereq with a course list
        major_requirement_lookup_table = {
            'minimum of':  
                {"name": "All Courses",
                "subreq_number": 1,
                "OK": True,
                "needs": {
            "hours": 0.0,
            "courses": 0,
            "course_list": [
                [
                {
                    "department": None,
                    "number": None
                }
                ]
            ]}}
        }
        for key in major_requirement_lookup_table:
            if key in req_name.lower():
                # sum all the hours, courses in the subreqs
                total = sum([subreq['needs']['hours'] + subreq['needs']['courses'] for subreq in subreqs_parsed])
                if total == 0:
                    subreqs_parsed = [major_requirement_lookup_table[key]]
                else:
                    print(f'warning-- not adding fake subreq for {req_name} because total is not 0')
                break
        
        reqs_parsed.append({
            'name': req_name,
            'req_number': len(reqs_parsed) + 1,
            'OK': req_OK,
            'needs': req_needs,
            'subreqs': subreqs_parsed
        })
    
    # Parse classes taken
    courses_taken = []
    assert courses_taken_section is not None
    courses = courses_taken_section.find_all('tr', class_='takenCourse')
    for course in courses:
        raw_term = course.find('td', class_='term').text.strip()
        term, year = raw_term[:2], int(raw_term[2:])
        raw_name = course.find('td', class_='course').text.strip()
        grade = course.find('td', class_='grade').text.strip()
        condition_code = course.find('td', class_='ccode').text.strip()
        # parse out name
        if condition_code == '>D': # Duplicated Course, ignore
            continue
        
        SPECIAL_TOPICS = {
            'CS': ['498']
        }
        match = re.match(r'([A-Z]{2,5})\s+([\d-]{3})(\s+[A-Z1-9]{1,3})?', raw_name)
        if match:
            department = match.group(1)
            number = match.group(2)
            section = match.group(3).strip() if match.groups == 3 else ''
            if number.endswith('--'):
                number = number[:-2] + '**'
            for topic in SPECIAL_TOPICS.get(department, []):
                if number == topic:
                    number = f'{number} {section}'
            courses_taken.append({
                # We count summer classes as spring classes
                'term': 'Spring' if term == 'SP' or term == 'SU' else 'Fall',
                'year': 2000 + year - (1 if term == 'WI' else 0),
                'department': department,
                'number': number,
                'is_transfer': grade == 'TR',

            })

    # Add semester int to courses taken
    first_year, first_term = get_first_term({'courses_taken': courses_taken})
    semester_offset = 1 if first_term == 'Spring' else 0

    for course in courses_taken:
        # Mark courses transferred into university before you took uni classes as 0
        if course['is_transfer'] and course['year'] < first_year or \
            (course['year'] == first_year and course['term'] == 'Fall' and first_term == 'Spring'):
            course['semester'] = 0
            continue

        course['semester'] = (course['year'] - first_year) * 2 + semester_offset + (0 if course['term'] == 'Spring' else 1)
    return {
        'requirements': reqs_parsed,
        'courses_taken': courses_taken
    }

def get_last_term(audit_result):
    last_term = None
    last_year = 0
    last_semester = -1
    for course in audit_result['courses_taken']:
        if course['semester'] > last_semester:
            last_term = course['term']
            last_year = course['year']
            last_semester = course['semester']
    return last_year, last_term, last_semester

def get_first_term(audit_result):
    first_term = None
    first_year = 9999
    for course in audit_result['courses_taken']:
        if (course['year'] < first_year or (course['year'] == first_year and course['term'] == 'Fall')) and not course['is_transfer']:
            first_term = course['term']
            first_year = course['year']
    return first_year, first_term
```

## Main Code

```
import lib
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass
from z3 import *
import re
import math
import sys
@dataclass
class Config:
    min_hours: int = 12
    max_hours: int = 18
    gpa_hard_threshold: float = 3.5
    max_hard_classes: int = 2
    max_semesters: int = 7

SPECIAL_TOPICS = {
    'ADV': [400, 490],
    'ANTH': [499],
    'ARTD': [499],
    'ARTS': [445],
    'CHLH': [494],
    'CI': [499],
    'CMN': [396, 496],
    'CPSC': [499],
    'CS': [498],
    'DANC': [451],
    'ECE': [498],
    'ENGL': [396, 461, 475],
    'EPSY': [490, 590],
    'FIN': [490],
    'GLBL': [499],
    'INFO': [390, 490],
    'IS': [390, 490, 496, 497],
    'JOUR': [460, 480],
    'KIN': [494],
    'LING': [490],
    'MACS': [395, 496],
    'MCB': [493],
    'MSE': [498],
    'MUS': [404, 499],
    'NPRE': [498],
    'PHIL': [380],
    'PS': [300],
    'PSYC': [496],
    'SOC': [396, 496],
    'SOCW': [380],
    'TE': [398]
}

def GetModel(config, sat):
    print('Solving...')
    if sat.check() == unsat:
        print('Unsatisfiable')
        exit()
    else:
        print('Satisfiable')
        m = sat.model()
        lookup = {}
        for i in range(config.max_semesters + 1):
            lookup[i] = []
        taking = []
        for item in m:
            if item.name().startswith('taking_') and m[item] == True:
                course = item.name().split('_')[1]
                taking.append(course)
        n = 0
        for item in m:
            if item.name().startswith('semester_') and m[item] == True:
                course = item.name().split('_')[2]
                n += 1
                
                semester = int(item.name().split('_')[1])
                if course in taking:
                    lookup[semester].append(f'{course} - {hour_values[course]} Cr / GPA: {round(gpas.get(course, 0),2)} ({"H" if is_class_hard.get(course, True) else "E"})')
        
        return lookup

def generate_prereq_constraint(last_semester, prereq, f_name):
    offset = 1 if prereq['is_concurrent'] else 0
    constraints = []
    # If the prereq is not in the catalog it's impossible to take
    if prereq['course'] not in is_taking_class_constraints:
        return None
    # For each possible semester to take the class
    for i in range(last_semester+1, config.max_semesters+1):
        # If the prereq is not in the catalog, skip it

        # Ensure that the prereq is taken before the class for each combination
        prereq_semesters = [semester_constraints[prereq['course']][0] == True] + \
            [semester_constraints[prereq['course']][j] == True for j in range(last_semester+1, i+offset)]
        if len(prereq_semesters) == 1:
            # TODO: possible optimization (check if we can state that this prereq is impossible to take like this)
            pass
        
        constraint = And(
            semester_constraints[f_name][i] == True,
            Or(prereq_semesters)
        )
        constraints.append(constraint)
    return Or(
        semester_constraints[f_name][0] == True, # If the class is already taken, don't worry about prereqs
        And(
            is_taking_class_constraints[prereq['course']] == True,
            Or(constraints)
        )
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Config()
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: python run.py <audit_file>')
        sys.exit(1)
    
    audit_contents = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()
    audit = lib.parse_audit(audit_contents)
    last_year, last_term, last_semester = lib.get_last_term(audit)
    print(last_semester)
    # print(json.dumps(audit, indent=2))
    # remaining = lib.get_remaining_requirements(audit)
    requirements = audit['requirements']
    sat = Solver()

    PREREQ_PATH = Path('..', 'datasets', 'uiuc-prerequisites.json')
    GPA_PATH = Path('..', 'datasets', 'uiuc-gpa-dataset.csv')
    GENED_PATH = Path('..', 'datasets', 'gened-courses.csv')
    CATALOG_PATH = Path('..', 'datasets', 'course-catalog-cleaned.csv')
    LIBERAL_PATH = Path('..', 'datasets', 'liberal_education.csv')

    prereqs = json.load(open(PREREQ_PATH, 'r', encoding='utf-8'))
    gpa = pd.read_csv(GPA_PATH)
    gened = pd.read_csv(GENED_PATH)
    catalog = pd.read_csv(CATALOG_PATH)
    liberal = pd.read_csv(LIBERAL_PATH)
    # deduplicate catalog
    # TODO handle multiple semesters
    catalog = catalog.drop_duplicates(subset=['Subject', 'Number', 'Name', 'Description']) # 'Year', 'Term',
    catalog = catalog[catalog.apply(lambda x: int(x['Number'].split(' ')[0]) < 500, axis=1)]
    # Drop 500 level courses (b/c of special topics they could be like 498 ASU)
    # Collapse all sections of the same course into one, summing counts of each grade
    gpa = gpa.groupby(['Subject', 'Number']).sum(numeric_only=True).reset_index()
    # drop rows older than 2019
    gpa = gpa[gpa['Year'] >= 2019]
    # Add GPA column
    # A+    A   A-  B+  B   B-  C+  C   C-  D+  D   D-  F
    mapping = {
        'A+': 4.0,
        'A': 4.0,
        'A-': 3.67,
        'B+': 3.33,
        'B': 3.0,
        'B-': 2.67,
        'C+': 2.33,
        'C': 2.0,
        'C-': 1.67,
        'D+': 1.33,
        'D': 1.0,
        'D-': 0.67,
        'F': 0.0,
    }
    # Each column has counts of each grade, calculate the weighted average
    gpa['GPA'] = gpa.apply(lambda row: sum([mapping[grade] * row[grade] for grade in mapping]) / sum([row[grade] for grade in mapping]), axis=1)
    # temporary - TODO more robust way to handle this
    is_class_hard = {}
    gpas = {}
    for index, row in gpa.iterrows():
        f_name = f'{row["Subject"]} {row["Number"]}'
        gpas[f_name] = row['GPA']
        if row['GPA'] < config.gpa_hard_threshold:
            is_class_hard[f_name] = True
        else:
            is_class_hard[f_name] = False
    # exit()
    # Course Name -> an int variable representing semester
    semester_constraints = {}
    is_taking_class_constraints = {}
    hour_values = {}

    # Add catalog course constraints
    seen = set()
    for index, row in catalog.iterrows():
        f_name = f'{row["Subject"]} {row["Number"]}'
        if f_name in seen:
            # raise Exception(f'Found duplicate course {f_name}')
            continue
        else:
            seen.add(f_name)

        credit_hours = row['Credit Hours'].replace('hours.', '')
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001775/find-all-floats-or-ints-in-a-given-string
        potential_hour_values = [int(float(h)) for h in re.findall(r"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?", credit_hours)]
        if 'TO' in credit_hours:
            potential_hour_values = [x for x in range(potential_hour_values[0], potential_hour_values[1]+1)]
        
        # temporarily only allow 3 hour classes (and prefer minimum course hours)
        if min(potential_hour_values) < 3:
            continue
        hour_values[f_name] = min(filter(lambda x: x >= 3, potential_hour_values))

        for i in range(last_semester+1, config.max_semesters+1):
            if f_name not in semester_constraints:
                semester_constraints[f_name] = {}
            semester_constraints[f_name][i] = Bool(f'semester_{i}_{f_name}')
        
        # This is for already taken courses
        semester_constraints[f_name][0] = Bool(f'semester_0_{f_name}')

        # Must take the class exactly once if it's a requirement
        is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] = Bool(f'taking_{f_name}')
        
        req_constraint = PbEq([(value, 1) for (key, value) in semester_constraints[f_name].items()], 1)
        sat.add(If(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name], req_constraint, True))
        # TODO: is there a better way to implement this?
        sat.add(If(req_constraint, is_taking_class_constraints[f_name], True))



    # Add semester hour constraints
    for i in range(last_semester+1, config.max_semesters+1):
        hour_constraint_low = PbGe([(And(semester_bools[i], is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True), hour_values[f_name]) for (f_name, semester_bools) in semester_constraints.items()], config.min_hours)
        sat.add(hour_constraint_low)
        hour_constraint_high = PbLe([(And(semester_bools[i], is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True), hour_values[f_name]) for (f_name, semester_bools) in semester_constraints.items()], config.max_hours)
        sat.add(hour_constraint_high)

    # Add semester hardness constraints
    for i in range(last_semester+1, config.max_semesters+1):
        constraint = PbLe([
            (And(semester_bools[i], is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True), 1) 
            for (f_name, semester_bools) in semester_constraints.items() if is_class_hard.get(f_name, True)
        ], config.max_hard_classes)
        sat.add(constraint)
    
    # Add already taken course constraints
    
    already_taken = []
    taken_courses = [f'{course["department"]} {course["number"]}' for course in audit['courses_taken']]
    for f_name in semester_constraints:
        if f_name in taken_courses:
            sat.add(semester_constraints[f_name][0] == True)
            for i in range(last_semester+1, config.max_semesters+1):
                sat.add(semester_constraints[f_name][i] == False)
            sat.add(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True)
        else:
            sat.add(semester_constraints[f_name][0] == False)
    

    # Add prereq constraints
    for index, row in catalog.iterrows():
        f_name = f'{row["Subject"]} {row["Number"]}'
        if f_name in prereqs and f_name in is_taking_class_constraints:
            and_clauses = []
            # Each section needs to be satisfied
            for section in prereqs[f_name]:
                or_clause = []
                # Each section only needs one of the prereqs
                for prereq in section:
                    # All ways to satisfy the prereq
                    clause = generate_prereq_constraint(last_semester, prereq, f_name)
                    if clause is None: # If we can't satisfy the prereq, don't add
                        continue
                    or_clause.append(clause)
                # TODO: If we can't satisfy any of the prereqs, don't add

                and_clauses.append(Or(or_clause))
            constraint = And(and_clauses) if len(and_clauses) > 0 else True

            # If we are taking the class, we need to satisfy all prereqs
            # Taking the class implies satisfying all prereqs
            if f_name not in taken_courses:
                sat.add(If(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True, constraint, True))

    # Add degree requirements
    for requirement in requirements:
        if requirement['OK'] == True:
            continue
        req_needs = requirement['needs']
        n_subreqs_needed = req_needs['subreqs']
        n_courses_needed = req_needs['courses']
        n_hours_needed = math.ceil(req_needs['hours'])
        subreq_constraints = {}
        subreq_names = []
        req_course_list = []
        for subreq in requirement['subreqs']:
            # print(subreq['name'])
            needs = subreq['needs']
            subreq_n_needed = needs['courses']
            subreq_n_hours_needed = math.ceil(needs['hours'])
            course_list_expr = []
            subreq_course_list = []
            for or_courses in needs['course_list']:
                or_clause = []
                for course in or_courses:

                    number, department = course['number'], course['department']
                    course_name = f'{course["department"]} {course["number"]}'
                    # Constraint: GENED / Liberal Ed requirements
                    # This should NOT be a part of an OR clause, as we could take multiple
                    if department == 'GENED':
                        assert len(or_courses) == 1
                        if number == 'LIB':
                            for index, row in liberal.iterrows():
                                f_name = f'{row["Subject"]} {row["Number"]}'
                                if f_name in is_taking_class_constraints:
                                    subreq_course_list.append(f_name)
                                    course_list_expr.append(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True)
                        else:
                            # Get gened courses with the column named number that isn't None
                            valid_courses = gened.loc[gened[number].notna()]
                            for index, row in valid_courses.iterrows():
                                f_name = row["Course"]
                                if row["Course"] in is_taking_class_constraints:
                                    subreq_course_list.append(f_name)
                                    course_list_expr.append(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True)
                    # Constraint: Take any course in a department
                    # This should NOT be a part of an OR clause, as we could take multiple
                    elif number is None:
                        assert len(or_courses) == 1 # This should be the only course in the OR clause
                    
                        if department is None: # Literally any class
                            for index, row in catalog.iterrows():
                                f_name = f'{row["Subject"]} {row["Number"]}'
                                if f_name in is_taking_class_constraints:
                                    subreq_course_list.append(f_name)
                                    course_list_expr.append(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True)
                        else:
                            valid_courses = catalog.loc[catalog['Subject'] == department]
                            for index, row in valid_courses.iterrows():
                                f_name = f'{row["Subject"]} {row["Number"]}'
                                if f_name in is_taking_class_constraints:
                                    subreq_course_list.append(f_name)
                                    course_list_expr.append(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True)
                    # Constraint: Standard Course
                    elif number.split(' ')[0].isdigit() and department is not None:
                        if course_name in is_taking_class_constraints:
                            subreq_course_list.append(course_name)
                            or_clause.append(course_name)
                    # Constraint: Any n-level course
                    elif number.endswith('**'):
                        assert len(or_courses) == 1 # This should be the only course in the OR clause
                        level = int(number[0]) * 100
                        if department is not None:
                            # This is disgusting
                            valid_courses = catalog[catalog.apply(lambda x: x['Subject'] == department and int(x['Number'].split(' ')[0]) >= level and int(x['Number'].split(' ')[0]) < level + 100, axis=1)]
                        else:
                            valid_courses = catalog[catalog.apply(lambda x: int(x['Number'].split(' ')[0]) >= level and int(x['Number'].split(' ')[0]) < level + 100, axis=1)]
                        # This should NOT be a part of an OR clause, as we could take multiple
                        for index, row in valid_courses.iterrows():
                            f_name = f'{row["Subject"]} {row["Number"]}'
                            if f_name in is_taking_class_constraints:
                                subreq_course_list.append(f_name)
                                course_list_expr.append(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True)
                    else:
                        raise Exception(f'Unknown course constraint: {course}')

                # Filter out bad courses
                or_clause = [course for course in or_clause if course in is_taking_class_constraints]
                # Don't add an empty or clause
                if len(or_clause) == 0:
                    continue
                # We must take at least one of the courses in the list to satisfy 1 course list of the subreq
                # TODO add to req_course_list
                course_list_expr.append(Or([is_taking_class_constraints[course] == True for course in or_clause]))

            
            # Express that we need to take at least n choose k courses in the future (after last semester)
            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081929/k-out-of-n-constraint-in-z3py
            if len(course_list_expr) == 0:
                if subreq['OK'] == False:
                    print(f'**WARNING** No valid courses for {subreq["name"]} -- must be manually inputted')
                    # DEFAULT TO ALL CLASSES (HACK)
                    for index, row in catalog.iterrows():
                        f_name = f'{row["Subject"]} {row["Number"]}'
                        if f_name in is_taking_class_constraints:
                            subreq_course_list.append(f_name)
                            course_list_expr.append(is_taking_class_constraints[f_name] == True)
                    
                else:
                    continue
            # We must satisfy at least n course lists to satisfy the subreq
            # print(course_list_expr)
            subreq_ncourses_constraint = PbGe([(course_expr, 1) for course_expr in course_list_expr], subreq_n_needed)
            if subreq_n_hours_needed > 0:
                sat.add(PbGe([
                    (And(is_taking_class_constraints[course] == True, semester_constraints[course][0] == False), hour_values[course]) 
                    for course in subreq_course_list
                ], subreq_n_hours_needed) == True
                )
            # print(n_needed, subreq_constraint)
            subreq_names.append(subreq['name'])
            if subreq_n_needed > 0 and subreq['subreq_number'] not in subreq_constraints:
                subreq_constraints[subreq['subreq_number']] = []
            if subreq_n_needed > 0:
                subreq_constraints[subreq['subreq_number']].append(subreq_ncourses_constraint)
            req_course_list.extend(subreq_course_list)
        # print(req_course_list, n_hours_needed, requirement['name'])
        # Add req course hours
        if n_hours_needed > 0:
            sat.add(PbGe([
                (And(is_taking_class_constraints[course] == True, semester_constraints[course][0] == False), hour_values[course]) 
                for course in req_course_list
            ], n_hours_needed) == True)

        if len(subreq_constraints) > 0 and n_subreqs_needed > 0:
            # Group by subreq_number
            # We must satisfy at least n subreqs to satisfy the req
            req_constraint = PbGe([
                (Or(subreq_constraint_list) == True, 1)
                for (i, subreq_constraint_list) in subreq_constraints.items()
            ], n_subreqs_needed)


            sat.add(req_constraint == True)
        else:
            pass
        

    
    model = GetModel(config, sat)
    print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))
```

The main feedback I want is how to segment out this code into functions. Additionally, it would be nice to have some ideas for a rewrite where I don't convert to a JSON object, and then convert back, but instead use Python classes/some other method.

Comment: @FMc it should be fixed now.

Comment: There's several input files missing to run it, would you be able to provide them too? Otherwise feedback will be a bit lacking since we can't run it (the `XYZ_PATH` ones).